# Should [database-restore] be a synonym of [restore]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

The tag [restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restore) has 461 questions. The tag [database-restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-restore) has 54 questions but no wiki or excerpt.

Furthermore, [database-restoring](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-restoring) is synonymized into [restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restore).

I can't imagine any reason for treating [database-restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-restore) differently from [database-restoring](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-restoring). It should also be a synonym of [restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restore).

Comment: Makes sense, [database-backup] and [backup] are already synonyms too.

Comment: There's probably more cases where [database-something] and [something] should be synonyms...

Comment: @Colin mention them in [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap-consultancy-) and I'll action them right away - the whole community synonym thing is broken imo.

Comment: I agree. I'd like to propose some synonyms too, but I can't because I have no cred. Well, not enough cred on the tags that require synonyms.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, I think it should, thanks for bring it up.

I've done the merge and created the synonym: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/restore/synonyms

Comment: Agreed.  Clearly they are one-and-the-same for all intents-and-purposes.